# Parse query on Pointer value returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

I have a table UserProfile that has a Pointer column (user) pointing to the corresponding User table. I'm trying to construct a simple query that grabs the UserProfile for a user object. However, the query is returning nil (object = the user object in my app):

```
let profileQuery = PFQuery(className: "UserProfile")
                    profileQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: object)
                    profileQuery.includeKey("user")
                    profileQuery.limit = 1
                    profileQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
                        (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                        if error != nil{
                            print(error)
                        } else if let results = results as? [PFObject]! {

                            for result in results {
                                self.profile = result
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Any idea why this query isn't working? Thanks!

Updated code using Mazel's solution:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error != nil {

            print(error)

        } else if let objects = objects as? [PFObject]! {

            for object in objects {

      let profileQuery = PFQuery(className: "UserProfile")
                    profileQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFObject(outDataWithClassName: "_User", objectId: "\(object.objectId!)"))
                    //profileQuery.includeKey("user")
                    profileQuery.limit = 1
                    profileQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
                        (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                        if error != nil{
                            print(error)
                        } else if let results = results as? [PFObject]! {

                            for result in results {
                                self.profile = result
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: the problem is in this line profileQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: object) but you didnt share what is object so hard to say anyway...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! object is the result of another query I run earlier in the app. I didn't include it so it doesn't confuse people. object is a PFUser from the User table. So my hope is to run another query that gets that user's UserProfile (that user is called object here in my query).

Answer (score 0):

maybe the pointer is stored differently, try to use this

```
profileQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFObject(outDataWithClassName: "_User", objectId: "\(object.objectId!)"))
```

and you can also remove this line profileQuery.includeKey("user")

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I still get `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` when it gets to the query results. I updated my question with the latest code. Xcode made me change `withoutDataWithClassName` to `outDataWithClassName`

Comment: and is your object optional or not, try to change it to object!.objectId!, and I checked xcode and it also made me change it to outDataWithClassName...

Comment: It does appear to be an optional. Updated my question. I added the other query that grabs the object so you have a better idea of what is going on (I understand it's hard to support without much info). Hope this helps

Comment: I dont know how many objects you will download in the first query but this is very poorly designed database scheme because for every object you download you are trying to download again something (and simultaneously).... think about your database scheme because this just sucks, network request are always very expensive! Just FYI pointers are good for 1:many relationships and Parse Relation for many:many...

Comment: I agree this isn't ideal. The reason why I split up the User table into User and UserProfile is because the default security settings of User. User now has private data and User Profile has public information. User to User Profile is a 1:1 relationship. Whats a better way to do this?

Comment: You can't set access levels on specific columns so I now need two tables. Before I new about access levels I had everything on User

Comment: you can easily override this with Masterkey in cloudcode. Read data from User class is "public". Create a function in cloud code and call this function from iOS or do some afterSave trigger. I used it this way in my app because the masterKey is stored only in the server and is never transported through the network so there shouldnt be any security issues..

Comment: How can I do this in cloud code? And can I easily export cloud code after parse.com closes?

Comment: what "this" means? You shouldnt use parse.com for developing your app, use the parse-server, the cloud code is running 98% exactly the same there as on parse.com...

Comment: Oh ok so the code is the same? Never used parse server / cloud code before